# Работа с UTF-8

Tags: кодировка, php

```
$s='цкнгшщзхфвпрлджчсмтб';
$test=$s[rand(0,19)].$s[rand(0,19)];
echo $test;
```

Файл в UTF-8 без Бома.
В HTML подписано, что UTF-8 тоже.
Выводятся краколзябры.

Comment: ошибка то какая выводится?

Comment: Ошибок не выводится, выводится текст в непонятной кодировке, типа: ���ш

Answer (score 2):

```
<? 
$s='цкнгшщзхфвпрлджчasdб';
$test=mb_substr($s, rand(0,19), 1, 'utf-8').mb_substr($s, rand(0,19), 1, 'utf-8');
echo $test;
?>
```

А что вы хотели, выбирая *байты* из строки в UTF8?)

Comment: Дак страшно ведь теперь жить, я думал как человек буду работать с буквами.. это видимо вы PEAR воспользовались ..

Comment: долго млин писал ответ :( тыопередил.

Comment: @jkeks есть [такая штука](http://forum.dklab.ru/php/advises/Php-funktsiiDlyaObrabotkiTekstaVKodirovkeUtf-8.html) и ей подобные) Не все так страшно.

Answer (score 1):

а ну тогда смотри

в кодировке UTF-8 1 символ занимает 2 байта и то что тебе выводится правильно.

```
$s[rand(0,19)]
```

Это выведет только часть символа. :)
переписывай код и читай чем отличается UTF-8 от windows-1251

Comment: не логично по идее... я хочу 10 символ, а оно мне сует 10-й байт.

Comment: на то он и UTF-8 чтобы иметь возможность на сайте, допустим иметь многоязычность для большого кол-ва языков :)